# Interactions in Moderated Regressions with multiple IVs

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have multiple IVs in my moderated regression model, but I want to look at the specific interactions with each of the IVs. Is this possible? I did run the regressions separately but because I have so many IVs, I have to use a Bonferroni correction which pushes my testing of sig. really low.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you clarify a little - why couldn't you look at the specific interactions you are interested in? What do you mean by running the regressions separately - do you mean you had the same outcome variable and ran separate regressions for different IVs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's reasonably possible depends on the details of your data and your model: how many observations, the nature of the outcome variable, the nature and number of your IVs, and how many/what level of interactions among IVs you want to evaluate. Please edit the question to provide that information.